# Do BEFORE UPDATE triggers affect mysqli_insert_id results?

Tags: php, mysql, last-insert-id

I have a mysql table which has a trigger attached, that logs changes in this table to a second one

```
CREATE TRIGGER log_table BEFORE UPDATE ON table1
  FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
    INSERT INTO log_table(filed) VALUES(NEW.field);
  END;
//
```

Now if I perform an INSERT INTO table1 from PHP an call `mysqli_insert_id()` afterwards.

Would that return the new ID in table1? Or the new ID in log_table?

Comment: You can't test this out yourself?

Comment: I'd take a hint from [this comment in PHP docs](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.insert-id.php#74923)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`LAST_INSERT_ID()` called after the INSERT statement will return the new ID in table1 (of the INSERT statement), not the one in the log_table (of the trigger).

This is documented in the manual section of [LAST_INSERT_ID](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/information-functions.html#function_last-insert-id):

> Within the body of a stored routine (procedure or function) or a
>   trigger, the value of LAST_INSERT_ID() changes the same way as for
>   statements executed outside the body of these kinds of objects. The
>   effect of a stored routine or trigger upon the value of
>   LAST_INSERT_ID() that is seen by following statements depends on the
>   kind of routine:
>
> - If a stored procedure executes statements that change the value of
>     LAST_INSERT_ID(), the changed value is seen by statements that follow
>     the procedure call.
> - **For stored functions and triggers that change the value, the value is
>     restored when the function or trigger ends, so following statements
>     will not see a changed value.**